# extdash package and invalid hyperref PDF tokens

Tags: hyperref, warnings

How can I silence the `hyperref` warnings:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\<let>-command' on input line 7.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\EXD@break' on input line 7.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 7.
```

when using the `extdash` package? I have tried to use `pdfstringdefDisableCommands` but couldn't find out what to put in there. What I would like to prevent is having to remember to use `\texorpdfstring` every time I use the `extdash` commands in sections.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \section{This is a test\-/Thing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa I have seen the duplicate, but I was searching for a solution that is not cluttering my section titles with additional commands. No chance to get this working with `pdfstringdefDisableCommands`?

Comment: You can do `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\-{-}}`, but you'll have to live with the slash in the bookmark. Unless `\-/` is the only dash you use in the section titles; in this case `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\-/{-}}` would do. Doing a look ahead is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, both versions work. Please add them as an answer so that I can accept this. I was searching for replacements on a much lower level of tex.

Comment: @languitar I added a more complex lookahead. If you also plan to use `\=`, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\-` is redefined by the package to do a look ahead.

Implementing such a look ahead for the bookmarks is not possible in the same way as when typesetting text.

A simple workaround is to add

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\-{-}}
```

but this will leave the slash in the bookmark.

If you only plan to use `\-/` in sectional titles, you can use

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\-/{-}}
```

A more complex look ahead can be obtained with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \languitar_bm_extdash:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {/}{-}
    {-}{\__languitar_bm_extdash_aux_i:n}
   }
   {#1}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__languitar_bm_extdash_aux_i:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {-}{\__languitar_bm_extdash_aux_ii:n}
   }
   {\textendash#1}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__languitar_bm_extdash_aux_ii:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {-}{\textemdash}
   }
   {\textemdash#1}
 }
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \- \languitar_bm_extdash:n
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{This is a test\-/Thing}

\section{This is a test\--Thing}

\section{This is a test\textendash Thing}

\section{This is a test\---Thing}

\section{This is a test\textemdash Thing}

\section{This is a test\-Thing}

\end{document}
```

[image]